# How can I reverse the function in javascript at the second click?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need that on the second click the function come back to the original height and width
Now the code is this:

```
<script>
function myBurger() {
    document.getElementById("burger").style.height = "200px";
    document.getElementById("burger").style.width = "300px";

    }
</script>
```

The website where I loaded the landing page (test) is this: http://figmentasergio.altervista.org/

Comment: document.getElementById("burger").style.height = (document.getElementById("burger").style.height == OLD_VALUE) ? NEW_VALUE : OLD_VALUE

Comment: @Marciano - Why should he?

Comment: @TimothyHa Where I have to insert the string?

Comment: @SergioVento - instead of the line in myBurger() please use the line I wrote.  First time it will set NEW_VALUE, second time it will change to OLD_VALUE

Comment: @LcSalazar Because it is easier.

Comment: @Marciano - Because it is..... what? Unnecessary use of a whole library for a small feature? Overkill? Pick your favorite...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use a global variable as a state indicator, like so:

**JavaScript**

```
var isExpanded = false;

function myBurger() {
    document.getElementById("burger").style.height = isExpanded ? "10px" : "200px";
    document.getElementById("burger").style.width = isExpanded ? "10px" : "300px";
    isExpanded = !isExpanded;
}
```

**[JSFiddle Link demonstrating this, here.](http://jsfiddle.net/98suuod4/)**

I changed a few variables (and the method that it's called) via the JSFiddle, but it's the exact same concept.

The line `isExpanded = !isExpanded` is a bit flip, where we set the `isExpanded` token to its inverse.

Comment: You don't need to.  It'll need a height and width to start, though.  The JSFiddle has the `10px` height and width set in the CSS to start.

Comment: You can, just set a `transition` property.  In this case, it would be something like: `transition: height 2s ease, width 2s ease;`

Comment: ok but the javascript that you wrote not work, now i load the code on the test online , can you see what is the problem please?

Comment: @SergioVento - The code in the answer is an example.  Please check [this link to JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/98suuod4/) for a real-world example.  Unfortunately, I'm not available at the moment for contracting work, so you'll need to implement the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

It's more convenient to toggle CSS class:

```
function myBurger() {
    document.getElementById("burger").classList.toggle('expand');
}
```

Where

```css
#burder.expand {
    height: 200px;
    width: 300px;
}
```

[`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList) is supported in [IE10+](http://caniuse.com/#search=classList). For older browsers you can use shims or go with simple className approach.

Comment: like this?
<script>
function myBurger() {
     document.getElementById("burger").classList.toggle('expand');
    
    }
</script>
and on css:
#burger{
 
 height: 10px;
 width: 10px;
 background-color: #fff;
 top: 10%;
 left: 10%;
 position: absolute;
 
 }
#burder.expand {
    height: 200px ;
    width: 300px ;
}
Becouse it not work :(

Comment: Typo: "#burger.extend" not "burder".

Comment: I wrote correctly burger in the original file that I loaded there: http://figmentasergio.altervista.org/
There is another mistake surely but I don't know what.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function and bind it to double click since the click event is already taken. The second function should revert any action the first function did.